# wait swallows echo from background process

Tags: bash

I am trying to use the "Parallel runs in N-process batches" approach from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216475/259719 and I am struggling to get it to work. Because my task involves an echo to stdout, which somehow get swallowed in this solution.

Does not work:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

N=8
for num in $(seq 10); do
    ((i=i%N)); ((i++==0)) && wait
    (
        echo "${num}"
    )&
done
```

Does work:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

N=8
for num in $(seq 10); do
    wait
    (
        echo "${num}"
    )&
done
```

Also works

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

N=8
for num in $(seq 10); do
    (
        echo "${num}"
    )&
done
wait
```

I am really struggling to understand why nothing is echoed out in the first example.

Comment: oh yes. My minimal example was not truely minimal. I had `set -e` in that script as well... removing that statement makes it work. Thanks a lot for helping out!

Comment: In the first example (not working), you use (i=i%N), but i is not defined previously.

Comment: with `set -e` even if I define `i` first, the first example does not work

Comment: to which value do you define `i`?

Comment: I set it to `i=0`

Answer (score 5):

```
set -e
((i=i%N))
```

Facts:

- `set -e` terminates the program if any command exits with nonzero exit status (except exceptions).
- `((` exits with nonzero exit status if the expression inside is equal to zero
- assignment `=` in arithmetic context is equal to the assigned value
- `i` is initialized with `0` or uninitialized, and uninitialized variables are equal to `0` in arithmetic context
- `i%N` is equal to 0

> why nothing is echoed out

The script terminates because `i%N == 0`, so `echo` is never executed.

---

```
if (( i++ % N == 0 )); then
    wait
fi
```

or

```
if (( i %= N , i++ == 0 )); then
```

or

```
(( i %= N )) || :
# or (( i %= N , 1 ))
if (( i++ == 0 )); then
```